# Mercurial .hgignore file on Windows

Tags: windows, version-control, mercurial

Using mercurial on Windows 10.

I have a .hgignore which reads so

```
syntax: glob
._site/**
```

When I run `hg status` I get

```
? .hgignore
? _posts\T1C.save
? _site\Tate\index.html
? _site\X1Ct\index.html
? _site\o
? o
? o1
```

Why do I get the files under `_site` directory even though I have `site/**` inside .hgignore

I tried changing the `\` in .hgignore to `/` - but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore an entire directory, just use the pure directory name.

```
syntax: glob
._site
```

Mercurial on Windows can handle backslashes in ignore files.